# Why Sitecore Image having Black border on Top and bottom?

Tags: sitecore

In my sublayout I'm trying to render image

HTML:

```
<sc:Image runat="server" ID="fldImage" Height="75px" Width="98px" />
```

CS code has following line to fill the image,

```cs
sitecoreImage.Field = SitecoreUtility.SITECORE_FIELD_LIST_IMAGE;
sitecoreImage.Item = sitecoreItem;
```

Image is getting Rendered with the black border on top and bottom.

while debug I see the Image URL like

`/~/media/Images/image-thumb.jpg?as=1&h=75&la=en&w=98&hash=920D0F90FR9BE29A9DC4131BAF1C5CD6BEA96F3B`

When try to request just the image with the following URL

`http://domain/~/media/Images/image-thumb.jpg?as=1&h=75&la=en&w=98&hash=920D0F90FR9BE29A9DC4131BAF1C5CD6BEA96F3B`

I see the image with the border.

But when I strip that `hash=920D0F90FR9BE29A9DC4131BAF1C5CD6BEA96F3B` from the url

`http://domain/~/media/Images/image-thumb.jpg?as=1&h=75&la=en&w=98`

I see the image is rendered without the black lines.

Why we are seeing the image with the black border in top and bottom?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are requesting the image with a width and height which is probably not the original causing Sitecore to adjust the image to your request. As it will preserve the aspect ratio, it is possible that a background color is added to do so. The default background color used is black, that is why you are seeing this. You can change the color with the `Media.DefaultImageBackgroundColor` setting.

Once you remove the hash, Sitecore will no longer make the adjustments as the url has been tampered with. I assume that the width and height of your image is also different then (the actual size, not what you see on screen).

Comment: Yes you are right, it is not the same size I'm requesting. But In my second url I'm passing the height and width again. I'm just stripping off the Hash query string. Why Hash query string is getting added in my URL? Is it something sitecore will do and I can prevent that?

Comment: Just to clarify, the hash is a security feature with image urls to stop attacks from requesting the image in every size possible, that has the potential to flood the requests and also to fill up large amounts of disk space. This this for details: http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2015/05/15/do-not-turn-sitecore-media-request-protection-off-and-protect-older-sitecore-versions-with-imageguard/